# Cast String to JQuery Object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question about jQuery and AJAX, I'm making this Ajax Call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
     console.log(jQuery(data));
      }
});
```

When I make in the success function

```
console.log(jQuery(data));
```

I get this value:

```
e.fn.e.init[136]
[0 … 10]
[11 … 21]
[22 … 32]
[33 … 43]
[44 … 54]
[55 … 65]
[66 … 76]
[77 … 87]
[88 … 98]
[99 … 109]
[110 … 120]
[121 … 131]
[132 … 135]
length: 136
__proto__: Object[0]
```

I need know as I make for obtain a DOM element of this variable "data":
Example

```
jQuery(data).filter('#example');
```

Comment: what do you return from your code?

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` and show us what `data` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is **really** big the Chrome console now breaks it up and shows it to you in smaller chunks.

Just click on one of the chunks to see the data.

Your selector should work **fine**! (well if you have the correct information in the `data` string)

Comment: This change in Chrome has sparked a lot of questions from people who confused about the new behavior.

Comment: Yes it's working fine since the log shows a jQuery object that holds 136 dom elements

Comment: @Rocket yea... It confused me as well when I first saw it.... :-\ They should have told people....